# Is there a way to prevent the Editor from modifying my HTML

Tags: tinymce, visual-editor

Is there a way to prevent the Visual Editor from modifying my HTML when creating a post or a page? I know it has good intentions in doing what it does, but sometimes I'd prefer it not to touch my HTML, yet render the HTML in visual mode.

Thank you!

**Sample of code used in editor:**

```
<td width="124" align="left" valign="top">
    <p style="line-height: 140%; font-size: 10px; color: #333; font-family: Arial; margin: 0; padding: 0 0 12px 0;">
        <strong>Team Demo of the New Shake Table</strong>
    </p> 
    <p>
        <strong>May 17, 4-6pm</strong>
    </p>
    <p style="line-height: 140%; font-size: 10px; color: #333; font-family: Arial; margin: 0; padding: 0 0 8px 0;">
        <strong>Tech Exhibition in Oslo</strong>
    </p>
    <p><strong>June 5-9, Halle</strong>
</td>
```

Comment: Could you provide some samples of what you're adding to the editor and what is getting removed.

Comment: <td width="124" align="left" valign="top">
<p style="line-height: 140%; font-size: 10px; color: #333; font-family: Arial; margin: 0; padding: 0 0 12px 0;"><strong>Team Demo of the New Shake Table</strong></p>
<p><strong>May 17, 4-6pm</strong></p>
<p style="line-height: 140%; font-size: 10px; color: #333; font-family: Arial; margin: 0; padding: 0 0 8px 0;"><strong>Tech Exhibition in Oslo</strong></p>
<p><strong>June 5-9, Halle</strong></td>

Comment: But I guess it's irrelevant, is it? I mean, since it is my blog is it not possible that I do <p><b>Test</p></b>? Wordpress can render it incorrectly (I'm thinking of say, IE or Firefox interpretation), but not just touch my code.

Comment: As long as your paragraphs have an attribute with a value on them TinyMCE/WordPress will leave them alone, eg. `<p class="none">` or `<p style="clear:none">` will get left alone, where as `<p>` or `<p class="">` will get stripped as part of the JS routine that replaces content when mode switching.

Comment: @t31os: I didn't know that, good tip.

Comment: Old post. Currently (Jan 2016) [Preserved Html Editor Markup Plus](http://wordpress.org/plugins/preserved-html-editor-markup-plus) is the best way to do this allowing you to enter all html and html5 while still switching between editors. Here are some [additional suggestions on doing it manually](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/214591/43806).

Answer (score 3):

This wordpress plugin seems to do the trick for my problem...

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/raw-html/

It does seem wrong that if I enter code in the html editor it then strips it unless I resort to cheats like the pluging or adding class tags that do nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a way to get TinyMCE to leave your HTML alone. This has been discussed in the WP Forum for ages. I stick with the HTML editor & write my code in another editor such as BBEdit first if it needs to be complicated.

As a general rule, I would not include that much inline styling in a post. It makes it *very difficult* to maintain or modify your styles in the future. This should all be defined in the theme stylesheet.

Comment: Avoiding inline styling is only great if you (or the wordpress user) has access to style.css. This is not viable if it's not. Content can be edited in the WP Editor, while style.css can only be modified in the file.

Comment: By the way, that's the point. We created the HTML from another editor, and copy-pasted the HTML code to the Visual Editor in Wordpress. TinyMCE keeps on insisting its way when toggling from HTML view to Visual view and back. I mean, come on, it should be fine as it is since we edited it in an external HTML editor. Back off Tiny MCE ;)

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen the Extend KSES plugin to allow disallowed HTML code?

http://tierra-innovation.com/wordpress-cms/category/plugins/

"This plugin extends the HTML functionality of the WordPress kses.php file, which states the allowable HTML that the post/page content editor will accept. It allows the site administrator to optionally enable support for currently disallowed HTML tags…"

Comment: This looks promising. I'll update you all after I have tinkered with this plugin.