# Visual editor keeps stripping my <a> tags

Tags: visual-editor, html-editor

My first post, please forgive me if I'm doing it wrong.

For some reason when switching to the visual editor WordPress will strip out my a tags.  "Don't use the visual editor" isn't an option, I'm making a website for clients and I'm trying to make it foolproof.  I don't want them to be able to go to the visual editor and accidentally have all the links stripped out.

This is a sample of the code.  When switching to visual and back to text, everything is there but the a tags.

```
<a href="https://www.url.ca" target="_blank" title="Donate Now">
<div class="donate-now">
<div class="wred">
<h1>Click here to Donate Now</h1>
<div class="wbumpred"> </div>
</div>
</div>
</a>
```

class="wred" styles a background colour and shape.
class="wbumpred" adds a small graphic element to the bottom of the "wred" element.

Please help!

Thanks,
Sarah

Comment: I'm not sure why the Block editor wouldn't "allow" this markup, that's why I decided to write my suggestion as a comment. If I had to do something similar I would have used the **Button** or the **Custom html** blocks. The Button block's markup is anchor in a `div`, both can have `:after` and `:before` pseudo-elements for the graphics and the styles; you can add custom class to the wrapping div via _Edit as HTML_. The other option is straightforward and "allows" any HTML code; you can toggle the _Preview_ tab so the markup doesn't scare the end users. Cheers!

Comment: Are you talking about the Block Editor or the Classic Editor?

Comment: @ValentinGenev, I'm not sure how to reply to your comment without creating a new comment.  I should have clarified, I'm using the classic Visual Editor and Text Editor, I've disabled the new Block Editor.  I don't want to have to teach clients how to use the block editor when I can teach them to use the classic visual editor as a very basic version of MS Word when they'll mostly just be modifying text and images.  Also, I've tried using block editors before, I really really really don't like them!   lol   :)

Comment: @WebElaine, the Classic Editor, I totally forgot about the new Block Editor, I have it disabled.

Comment: @SarahMorrow Take a look at this, it should answer your question [TinyMCE editor is breaking my beautiful HTML](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/214588/tinymce-editor-is-breaking-my-beautiful-html).